# Select Query ADO (loop through the tables)

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a requirement that In a database (Ms Access) I need to run through particular tables and inside of the tables I have to select particular fields(I can predefine both tables and fields).

I don't want to duplicate required field names and required tables names everywhere. I will store those details in a class. When I select the data as below what is the optimized way to make the string query for each and every statement by using DataReader (ADO.NET) (Assume number of fields varies for each and every table as below)

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 from table1Name
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5  from table2Name
```

Could you please list down the best practices since I am new to ADO.NET. I gained some of the best practices from this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx). I need a best way to loop through the tables by using select query

Comment: My first recommended "best practice" would be to not use MS Access :).

Comment: @Dan Yes I agree with you. This is a old system and unfortunately I have to stick with this option currently

Comment: Good.  That is the only justifiable reason for using MS Access.

Comment: There is metadata information available that gives you table and column information.  Use this to control your loops etc.  Look for system tables.  A possibly useful link: http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/Microsoft-Access-System-Tables.htm

Comment: @mcalex, Please check my question above, Assume I know the table names and required fields already. How I can match my requirement with your answer. Could you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: use the same concept.  set up structures (arrays, linked lists etc) containing the tables you want, with the columns from each table and loop through the structures populating the queries

Comment: @mcalex, thanks for the quick response. Assume the case like this, I have to select certain fields from a table. How you would modify the below statement. SELECT [Name] FROM [MSysObjects] WHERE [Type] = -32764 [Hope type is equal to 1, since I need to access local table